# Why some symbols are not found in the library when I run ./configure?

Tags: compilation, linker, autotools, configure

I'm trying to install [8086 emulator](http://i8086emu.sourceforge.net/) from sources. 
I run `./configure` and see the following warnings in the output:

```
checking for g_signal_emit in -lgtk-x11-2.0... no
configure: WARNING: Without GTK there will be no GTK-GUI of i8086emu!
checking for XkbGetMap in -lgdk-x11-2.0... no
configure: WARNING: Without GTK there will be no GTK-GUI of i8086emu!
checking for g_malloc in -latk-1.0... no
configure: WARNING: Without ATK there will be no GTK-GUI of i8086emu!
checking for g_log in -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0... no
configure: WARNING: Without GTK there will be no GTK-GUI of i8086emu!
```

What can cause it? Does it mean that I have the wrong version of library? Or maybe the library should be recompiled with other configuration? What should I do if I face that kind of problem?

**UPD:**
`g_signal_emit` symbol belongs not to the `-lgtk-x11-2.0` but to the `-lgobject-2.0`. If I run:

```
env LIBS='-lgobject-2.0' ./configure
```

then I have

```
checking for g_signal_emit in -lgtk-x11-2.0... yes
```

The situation becomes even more confusing.

Comment: I've failed to understand what is going on. Switched to emu8086 (only Windows) running via wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can cause it?

The actual warning messages, which are provided by the project developer, are clearer than the "checking ..." messages, which are standard Autoconf messages explaining what it is doing, not the purpose of doing it.

The point of those checks is not actually to locate the particular symbols.  That's just a means to the end of checking whether a particular library can be located by the linker.  The symbol that Autoconf tries to get the linker to resolve is chosen by the project developer, and it should be one that is characteristic of the wanted library.

That the checks fail means either the libraries in question were *not* located by the linker, or that they do not contain the specified symbols.  The former is far more common.  The latter could arise from a simple bug, or because the wrong library or wrong version of it is chosen by the linker.  It's also possible that an unusable version of the library is found (wrong architecture, inaccessible, ...), which is sort of both.

The project developer appears to have chosen to emit additional messaging when these checks fail, apparently because it is still possible to build the software, but you would get a reduced-capability version.

> Does it mean that I have the wrong version of library? Or maybe the library should be recompiled with other configuration?

As I have already described, there are multiple possibilities.  The `configure` script will have written a log file in the build directory that provides more detail about what exactly it tried and how it failed, with error messages.  You should consult that log for details.

> What should I do if I face that kind of problem?

Start by calling up and reading the configuration help:

```
./configure --help
```

Much of it is boilerplate, but it may describe relevant options that you can pass to `configure` to resolve the situation.

You may also find useful information in the project documentation.  Coverage and quality vary widely, but usually the docs will tell you what version of which third-party libraries you will need.

You can also consult the configuration log for details of the failing checks.

The information you glean in these ways must guide how you proceed from there.  The solution might be to install additional libraries or to pass an appropriate argument to `configure`, but in some cases you need to update and rebuild the project's build system and maybe its source to handle your environment.

A few tips for simple cases:

- *Building* a library is not the same thing as *installing* it.  The linker generally will not find uninstalled libraries.
- On systems that make a distinction, you need the development packages for the libraries in question.  The runtime packages are not normally sufficient on such systems.
- Make sure you have the right library flavor.  I have occasionally beaten my head against the wall, trying to discover why `configure` seems not to see the library that I can prove is installed, eventually discovering that I had the wrong library architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit).
- Some packages perversely install their libraries outside the linker's standard search path.  Clueful clients of such packages often provide a way to pass the path to `configure` via command-line arguments, but if not, you may be able to use the `LDFLAGS` environment variable, *e.g.*

  ```
  LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/libfoo.d" ./configure
  ```